# Inequality in Hilbert spaces

Tags: inequality, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Prove that  $\sqrt{||a+b||^2+||c+d||^2} \leq \sqrt{||a||^2+||b||^2} + \sqrt{||c||^2+||d||^2}$, when $a,b,c,d$ are vectors in a Hilbert space $H$.

My attempt:

$$ ||a+b||^2=||a||^2+||b||^2+(||a+b||^2-||a-b||^2)/2 $$
$$ ||c+d||^2=||c||^2+||d||^2+(||c+d||^2-||c-d||^2)/2 $$

where  I have used the fact that $<a,b>=\frac{||a+b||^2-||a-b||^2}{4}$

Then, I can write the LHS to be,

$$ \sqrt{ ||a||^2+||b||^2+(||a+b||^2-||a-b||^2)/2 + ||c||^2+||d||^2+(||c+d||^2-||c-d||^2)/2 } $$
I think I need to use $\sqrt{x+y} \leq \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}$ when $x,y \geq 0$, but I cannot proceed from the above step.
Can someone help?

Comment: Hint: prove that $H \times H$ is an inner product space with the inner product:$$\langle (a, b), (c, d) \rangle_{H \times H} := \langle a, c \rangle + \langle b, d \rangle.$$What is the norm with respect to this inner product?

Comment: $||(a,b)||=\sqrt{||a||^2+||b||^2}$, so the expression is basically the triangle inequality in this space.

Comment: Yep. That'd be the way I'd prove it.